# Arithmetic properties of erf functions

Tags: pr.probability

I was messing around with Benford's law trying a proof to fill up time on a Saturday, and I ran into a problem. I have the equation $\frac{\mathrm{erf}(2x)-\mathrm{erf}(x)}{\mathrm{erf}(10x)-\mathrm{erf}(x)}$ and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to (or if I even can) reduce this. I'm an undergrad, so any tricks of the trade I don't know about error functions out there?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find much in the way of simplification of the expression that you have...

Comment: I don't see an equation.

Comment: Anthony is right, there is no chance of a more explicit form.  You can of course write it as the quotient of two definite integrals and you can also compute various series expansions.